# How to use Dagger 2 in Android with a base Activity and Fragments?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm new using Dagger and I want to use it in my app. The hierarchy of my app is very simple, I have 3 activities(A1, A2, A3), all of them extends from one (BaseActivity). The activity A3 uses 3 fragments (F1, F2, F3). These are the components and modules that I defined:

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        ActivityModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MyApp myApp);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

**ActivityModude**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract A1 contributeA1();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract A2 contributeA2();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentBuildersModule.class)
    abstract A3 contributeA3();
}
```

**FragmentBuildersModule**

```
@Module
public abstract class FragmentBuildersModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract F1 contributeF1();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract F2 contributeF2();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract F3 contributeF3();
}
```

And when I try to build the app I get this error log:

```
Error:(35, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> is injected at
dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.<init>(injectorFactories)
dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> is injected at
dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.supportFragmentInjector
com.we.go.cuba.ui.A1 is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
A binding with matching key exists in component: com.we.go.cuba.di.ActivityModule_ContributeA3.A3Subcomponent
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to use `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` instead of `AndroidInjectionModule`